# After orientation change Presented Controller position changes back in iOS 8

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uiinterfaceorientation

I am implementing presentation of UIViewController (modal) on top of another UIViewController. I want the presentedController to be at particular Y position instead of center of the parent controller. This Y position is different in both Portrait and landscape. After orientation change presentedcontroller has brought back to center. Here is the piece of code I have tried..

Target device OS version: iOS 8. Not using autolayout as it's an existing codebase.

```
- (IBAction)PresentControllerSelected:(id)sender
{

    PresentedViewController *vcPresented = [[PresentedViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PresentedViewController" bundle:nil];
    vcPresented.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    vcPresented.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;


    vcPresented.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 250);

    [self presentViewController:vcPresented animated:NO completion:^{


    }];

    CGRect r;
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
    {
        r = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2 - (500/2),
                       self.view.bounds.size.height/2 - (250/2) + 100,
                       500, 250);

    }
    else{
        r = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2 - (500/2),
                       self.view.bounds.size.height/2 - (250/2) - 100,
                       500, 250);

    }

    vcPresented.view.superview.frame = r;
    vcPresented.view.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

In Presenting View Controller if i add the orientation change delegate methods its not updating the presented controller' frame.

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];


    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

        CGRect r;
        if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
        {
            r = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2 - (500/2),
                           self.view.bounds.size.height/2 - (250/2) + 100,
                           500, 250);

        }
        else{
            r = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2 - (500/2),
                           self.view.bounds.size.height/2 - (250/2) - 100,
                           500, 250);
        }

        self.presentedViewController.view.superview.center = CGPointMake(r.origin.x+r.size.width/2, r.origin.y+r.size.height/2);

    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        // Do Nothing
    }];
}
```

and here is the presentedController class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    CGRect r = self.view.frame;
    self.view.frame = r;

    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
    {
        r = CGRectMake(self.presentingViewController.view.bounds.size.width/2 - (500/2),
                       self.presentingViewController.view.bounds.size.height/2 - (250/2) + 100,
                       500, 250);

    }
    else{
        r = CGRectMake(self.presentingViewController.view.bounds.size.width/2 - (500/2),
                       self.presentingViewController.view.bounds.size.height/2 - (250/2) - 100,
                       500, 250);

    }
    self.view.superview.center = CGPointMake(r.origin.x+r.size.width/2, r.origin.y+r.size.height/2);
}
```